# How to remove accounts displayed in gcloud auth list?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

The command

*gcloud auth list*

returns a list of accounts as seen in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot of gcloud auth list output]

How to remove some or all of the non-active accounts from the display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
gcloud auth revoke [email account]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error:

ERROR: gcloud crashed (JSONDecodeError): Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
gcloud info --run-diagnostics

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34984788)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).